# Flutter Firebase updated display name successfully but still can't access. It is null

Tags: firebase, flutter

[image]

display name of firebase user is updated but still the getter was called on 'null'.

I registered with email and password.

The function used for registering is....

```
  void _registerAccount() async {
final User user = (await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
  email: emailC.text,
  password: passwordC.text,
))
    .user;

if (user != null) {
  if (!user.emailVerified) {
    await user.sendEmailVerification();
  }
  await user.updateProfile(displayName: usernameC.text);
  final user1 = _auth.currentUser;
  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => Home(
            user: user1,
            username: usernameC.text,
          )));
} else {
  bool _isSuccess = false;
}
}
```

passwordC,usernameC and emailC are the controllers.
After, signing up I wanted to show 'Display name' on the screen. but I tried to print it and see first, it showed null.

This is my build method of homepage...

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
initialize();
print('Reached here');
print(widget.user.displayName);
return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: Container(
        child: Column(
      children: [
        Text(''),
        Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Logout"),
              onPressed: () {
                FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
              }),
        ),
      ],
    )),
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
      onTap: (index) {
        setState(() {
          currentindex = index;
        });
      },
      currentIndex: currentindex,
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text("Home"), icon: Icon(Icons.account_balance_wallet)),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text("Home"), icon: Icon(Icons.search)),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text("Home"), icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle)),
      ]),
);
```

initialize method here is to call these two methods

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

initialize method cannot be problem anyway.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

FirebaseAuth.currentUser() will only detect changes made locally to the user, but if any server-side changes occur, it won't detect them, unless FirebaseUser.reload() is called first so you have to call

```
await user.reload();
```

after the update() is called.

Comment: Oh! man I got it. It's working now. Thank you so much.